# Disable the size changing of \vec

Tags: brackets, accents, size

I would like to use this macro :

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}
```

But doing

```
\norm{\vec F}
\lVert \vec F \Rvert
```

Yields to this

[image]

Obviously `\vec` is changing the "size" of the argument, which I would like to disable, in order to achieve the second form above.

Comment: Define `\norm` differently, see section 3.6 in [the mathtools manual](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf). Then you can decide upon the size of the doublebars more easily.

Comment: I will not remove `\left` and `\right` since I want to use the macro for a general purpose. It's `\vec` thats needs to be changed.

Comment: You gain nothing, and lose much, if you insist in using `\left` and `\right` for every pair of fences.

Comment: Stating facts without explanations will not change my mind. You can't expect anyone to be convinced of anything without a proof. The `\smash` command really does the job for me and I have nothing to complain about for now.

Comment: If you define it using mathtools, then `\norm*{stuff}` will be the same as your current `\norm{stuff}`.  But if `stuff` turns out to be too tall, you can use the optional argument `\norm[\big]{stuff}` to resize it.

Comment: About the “facts without explanation”, consider `\[ \frac{1}{\norm{\smash{\vec{F}}}} \]` and [see (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYb7T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conciseness sake, I prefer not using Sandy G's relevant solution.
I took Mico's advice about the usage of `\left \right` and I came up with this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\Vert' macro
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\mleft\Vert #1 \mright\Vert}
\let\dvec\vec
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\smash{\dvec #1}}
```

While keeping in mind that `\dvec` can be used in the rare [cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYb7T.png) mentioned by egreg.

```
\[
    \norm{\vec v} \quad  \norm{\vec V} \quad \norm{\frac{\vec F}{\lVert \dvec F \rVert}}
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. Then you can manually adjust the delimiter size (which you should do in general instead of using `\left` and `\right`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\Vert}{\Vert}

\begin{document}

$\norm{F} \quad \norm{\vec F} \quad \norm[\big]{\vec F} \quad \norm[\Big]{\vec F}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use automatic sizing of the "fences" produced by `\norm`, I suggest you do so with `\mleft` and `\mright` -- the two user-level macros of the [mleftright](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package -- instead of `\left` and `\right`. Using `\mleft` and `\mright` will avoid creating excess whitespace around the expression.

Only if you absolutely must, you could use `\smash` to squash the height of `\vec{F}`. However, do be aware that using `\smash` is not a panacea. In fact, its use may have a host of unintended and undesirable consequences; please see @egreg's comment below your query for such an example. To sum up: Do consider using the appoach, set forth in [Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678954/5001), that employes the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro (provided by the `mathtools` package) to create a macro called `\norm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\Vert' macro
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\mleft\Vert #1 \mright\Vert}

\begin{document}
$\norm{\vec{F}}$
$\norm{\smash{\vec{F}}}$
$\lVert \vec{F} \rVert$
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my comment to the OP about `\smash`.

Comment: @egreg - thanks. My answer was not meant to be taken as an endorsement of using `\smash`-ing the argument of the (questionably designed) `\norm` macro. Instead, it was more about using `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right`. But I see now that its purpose could be misunderstood. I'll edit my answer to remove this risk.